# Jest importing re-exported named exports

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test modules which import re-exported named exports. Basic `import` statement work properly (both default and named) except the case the title suggests.

A repro-repo: https://github.com/bali182/babel-jest-export-everything-bug
(I think it's a problem with Jest but after opening an [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5533) devs suggested that it's a configuration problem, so I'm asking here)

To demonstrate the issue here:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "babel-jest-export-everything-bug",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest --config .jestrc.json"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "jest": "^21.2.1"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    [ "es2015", { "modules": "commonjs" } ],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

**.jestrc.json**

```
{
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
  }
}
```

**namedExports.js**

```
export const x = 1
export const y = 2
export const z = 3
```

**reExports.js**

```
export * from './namedExports'
export default { hello: 'world' }
```

**reExports.test.js**

```
import Foo, { x, y, z } from './reExports'

describe('testing re-exports', () => {
  it('will never get to this method', () => {
    expect(x).toBe(1)
  })
})
```

Which then fails with

> ```
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
>
>   at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/reExports.test.js:1:120)
>       at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
> ```

Any suggestions what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `babel-preset-env`

Comment: Why do you need a ´.jestrc.json´file?

Comment: I ran into the same - have you sold the issue?

Comment: @DmitrySemenov I gave up on using this kind of exports/imports

Answer (score 1):

**solution**

this happens due to **transform-runtime** plugin, in order to fix it, just updated your **.babelrc** file with

`["transform-runtime", { "polyfill": false }]`

*see example of my file:*

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "jsx-vue-functional",
    "transform-vue-jsx", ["transform-runtime", { "polyfill": false }],
    "transform-decorators-legacy",
    "lodash"
  ],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": [
        "transform-vue-jsx", 
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", 
        "dynamic-import-node",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
      ]
    },
    "cli": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": [
        [ "babel-plugin-webpack-alias", { "config": "./aliases.config.js" } ],
        "transform-vue-jsx", 
        "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", 
        "dynamic-import-node",
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```